# DLLs or examples to support writing a shp, shx, dbf file as memory stream for uses on Azure website?

Tags: shapefile, web-mapping, web-service

I'm trying to read/write shapefiles for a web service for an azure website and I do not have the luxury of accessing the local file storage (which means that reading/writing from/to disk is out of the question as many of the DLLs read and write via local disk). I've come across libaries such as DotSpatial, NetTopologySuite, ShapeLib, GDAL's Ogr2Ogr which does very nice things for desktop when it comes to read/write shapefiles, but since I don't have access to local disk, I have to come up with something different.

What I have so working so far is reading the dbf and shp file from a blob storage and parsing the binaries to get the geometry and property data and send that down via json or text.

I'm currently working exporting my data (edit: the data is stored in SQL server table on Azure, this is not a geom table, the lat/lng are in floats and properties columns of the table) to shp, dbf, and shx files in webapi and send that down as a zip for download. What I come up with is building the binary array, which is very tedious. I'm hoping that there's a tool out there that can facilitate this process.

Comment: GeoServer's WFS can export in zipped shapefile and I believe it doesn't write it to disk as an intermediate step so maybe you can look at how they do it